# Apparent pedal force improvement from swept back handlebars; why not use them?

Tags: handlebars, geometry

As a teenager a friend found some antique swept back motorcycle handlebars that had the same expansion nut type fitting as my bike and we had to try them out; the handles just touched the front of the saddle when turning very sharply - with any kind of speed, not at all. The point is the amount of force that could be applied to the pedals was greater, because pulling up on the handles was close to being in line with the force down. As analogy, it was like lifting a weight in a straight line from standing above position instead of having it out at arms length and trying to lift. My father immediately ordered their removal as unsafe - it certainly made it (too) easy to wheelstand both from centre of mass being further back (upright position) and that greater force. However, if a bike were designed to achieve that in line pull on handlebar/push on pedals, would performance, especially uphill/against the wind be improved?  I think recumbent designs may use this effect.

Comment: As far as I can tell, most pros even use the drops (i.e. an even lower hand position) during sprint finishes. [example](https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/articles/2015/07/stage5-field-sprint-1462813922.png?crop=1xw:0.988xh;center,top&resize=980:*) I think you underestimate the strength of the back muscle.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. The aerodynamics seems an obvious drawback - that a recumbent would fix, with other drawbacks instead. Total cardio capacity (Adam) makes sense, although I expected the work spread across more muscle groups would aid stamina as well as max force. I expected more use of back muscles - not arms - in a posture better suited for them. My recreational riding never really used toe clips - but I see how that puts more muscles to work for more pedal force; it always felt awkward, never did it enough to develop the needed strength and endurance.

Comment: Too old now for anything BUT a "granny bike" posture I find... with electric boost for hilly local terrain; I could use more swept back handlebars just to ease bad shoulder joints.

Comment: I don’t like age as an excuse. Core strength helps a lot. Bad shoulder joints are often just muscle imbalance or bad posture (leading to impingement etc.). “Aggressive” positions require training but completely relaxed, upright positions are not great either.

Comment: You get even more pedal force improvement on a recumbent bike/trike.  But I can tell you that I'm slower on my recumbent trike than on my road bike.  The occasions when I need to push against the seat and muscle up a hill are relatively rare.

Answer (score 14):

For one thing, the aerodynamics are terrible. For another, most cycling is not dependent on peak power, but on sustainable power, for which leg strength (or body strength) isn’t as important as cardiovascular capacity.

Some recumbents do use bars like the ones you mention, but the geometry is so different that muscle recruitment is also very different.

Comment: I've upvoted your answer. In addition and more generally, max pedal force usually doesn't coincide with max power. Here are two plots: http://anonymous.coward.free.fr/wattage/components/maxW-maxN.png and http://anonymous.coward.free.fr/wattage/components/maxW-maxN-2.png. The bottom two panels of the first plot show pedal force and power for segments of a longer ride. Max power doesn't occur at max force. The 2nd plot shows how pedal force, cadence, and power were related.

Comment: Interesting, thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Many cruisers have swept-back bars, as do some bikes designed for more athletic riding (notably [Jones Bikes](https://jonesbikes.com)).

I have two bikes set up with Jones bars (one an aggressive hardtail mountain bike, and one a cargo bike). In line with your experience, I’ve found that muscle recruitment and force alignment are affected by having a vertical line through the grip and the handle bar, and I can apply significant downward pedal force. In conjunction with wide tires, I've found that this allows for an interesting ``hiking" motion over roots and rocks.

In places where wind resistance is a factor, the upright position does amplify this. (Jones' design compensates for this by offering alternative grips in a more forward position).

Comment: I'd say the Jones bar's aren't so much _swept back_ as _arrowed forwards_.

Comment: @leftaroundabout The Jones bars are very much swept back -- the ends of my grips are significantly further back than they were with the original "slightly swept" straight bars. (The Surly Moloko bar, by contrast, is arrowed forward, with the ends of the bar pretty much lining up with the ends of the straight bar.)

Answer (score 5):

In addition to aerodynamics, there are two more things:

- It is more efficient use of your muscles to pedal faster in lower gear, except maybe for very short bursts
- Clipless pedals or toe clips and straps also allow one to push pedals harder than one's weight, but don't have the problem with aerodynamics or require arm strength.

Comment: The first point is key here: Whenever you feel the need to pull on the handlebar, your gear is not low enough.

Comment: Don't explain it to me, explain it to these guys: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qj6SPmQLrLE&t=2m0s

Comment: Yes, one of the most absurd types of cycle sports... And still I claim that they are riding in a way too high gear, even though they are doing it precisely for the challenge of accelerating in a way too high gear.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by "more efficient to pedal faster in lower gear." At the same power, gross metabolic efficiency for most individuals is higher at moderate to low cadence than at high cadence. However, metabolic efficiency often isn't the goal of performance.

Comment: @R.Chung okay, poor choice of words. The idea I was after was that if you're pedaling with force that requires pulling up from handlebars or the other pedal, you're probably not going to be able to maintain the effort for a longer time.

Comment: @cmaster-reinstatemonica - needing to pull up on h-bars on standard bicycle indicates too high gear, yes, but this would be deliberately shifting the work to different muscles, so not sure it applies. Note, I think it would not be arms but mostly back muscles. Note also I am not insisting it would be better overall; it IS a question.

Comment: @KenFabian Well, of course you are right when you say that pulling on the handle bar does activate muscle groups that would otherwise not be used in cycling. Nevertheless, the power output of a cyclist is not limited by activated muscle groups, but rather by the cardiovascular system. A cyclist spinning at 90 rpm easily burns all the nutrients and oxygen that their blood can deliver to their leg muscles. This is not the case when that same cyclist is pulling their handlebars at 30 rpm: That stresses the muscles and joints with strong forces while delivering less power to the wheels.

Comment: @cmaster-reinstatemonica - instead of sustained power, what about for sprints?

Comment: @KenFabian Still same thing: Muscles need to move to output power. Power is proportional to force times cadence, but the force that you can put on your pedals does not grow linearly with the time you take for a revolution of your pedals. This is definitely true for any cadence at or below 60 rpm, likely extends higher. There is a reason why racers aim for a 90 rpm cadence...

Comment: @cmaster-reinstatemonica have you ever seen a bike race? Can you point to a video that shows someone sprinting at 90rpm?

Comment: @ojs What I remember from seeing the Tour de France is, that they rather spin faster than slower during sprint. I would do that as well, delaying the switch to a higher gear a bit so my legs spin faster. The only point where I've seen racers go below their optimal cadence is during ascents where they need to go out-of-saddle anyways to have their center of mass at the right place over the pedals.

Comment: @cmaster-reinstatemonica yes, the sprinting RPMs are consistently around 120 (check the link in comments to top answer too). I think the meme about 90RPM being optimal to every situation and you need bazillion gears to keep the cadence constant at all speeds needs to be forgotten.

Comment: @ojs Please note that I didn't say "racers do 90 rpm all the time", but rather "racers *aim* for a 90 rpm cadence". And I said that to underline that a low cadence with a lot of force on the pedals is not a smart thing to do (because the people who really need the last bit of power pedal quite fast). I was never in any disagreement with you, I only do 60 rpm, btw. And yes, more gears always help, but even more so a large gear *range*. If you want to be able to pedal the same cadence at 50 km/h as at 5 km/h, you need a 10x gear spread. Pity, it's hard to get such gearing...

Answer (score 3):

What you've done there is reinvented what's called a "sit up and beg" bike. Upright position with swept back bars. It's an old school upright bike of the sort your grandparents might have ridden, along with anyone Dutch.

Why they're not so common any more is primarily a matter of fashion, replaced initially by mountain bikes (cooler) and then by hybrids (mountain bikes with road gears and tyres), though I've noticed the hybrids of recent years increasingly moving back towards those swept back bars.

Don't get the idea they're in any competition with drop bars and road bikes. For getting around town at low speeds the upright position gives you much better all round visibility and easy pedaling.

Comment: Recently published video about Dutch granny bikes, might be fun for you to see: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aESqrP3hfi8 Not Just Bikes.

Comment: @Separatrix, Willeke -  my riding tends to be leisurely and I like the more comfortable upright riding posture.

Comment: @KenFabian, perhaps a granny bike is the best option for you then :) The older I get the more I prefer an upright posture, to the point where I'm going to have to replace my bike as the bars won't go high enough for what I now want.

Comment: A truly uprigth position is a back killer if you ride more than occasionally.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica, perhaps if you're trying to ride long distances or at high speeds, but it's not the right style of bike for that. Granny bikes are for going to the shops, they're for getting about the place, they're a tool not a hobby.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica,if your bike is designed for the position and adjusted to your body, it is not going to hurt your back. Your sit-bones, or the skin below them, are likely to be the least happy.

Comment: @KenFabian, I used to sit completely upright on my bike(s) and have gone a step further, I am now riding recumbents.

Comment: @Separatrix - I am not sure what I did was quite the same - the h-bars I used swept back a LOT more than any granny bike; the grips were almost at my sides. It really was like the forces applied were in-line, from a seated posture, more so than what is considered "swept back". I remember worrying something would break - or the handles would bend; it seemed like a large increase in force.

Comment: @KenFabian the handlebar bends because pulling the ends of the long bars produces more torque for the same force, not because because you're using more force.

Comment: @ojs - Yes there was more force - a LOT more force - as well as length of handle to bend. But those handlebars were very thick walled without much flex. I suspect the frame itself was more at risk.